# maximum absolute error of difference of two functions

Tags: plotting, approximation

I have a function `f(x) = (0.5x^2 + 3x)e^(−i2π(0.35x^2+2x))` and its approximation function `F(x) = e^(50ix−2ix^2 cotα−625i sin2α) with, 0.1 < α ≤ π/2`. I want list plot of α against maximum absolute error `er(x,α) = max x∈[−π,π]|f(x)−F(x)|`. I tried the following *Mathematica* command:

```
lst = Table[{alpha, 
     Abs[FindMaximum[
        Evaluate[Re[err[50, alpha, x]]], {x, -Pi, Pi}][[1]]]}, {alpha, 
     0.1, Pi/2, 0.01}] // Quiet;
ListPlot[lst, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["α", 16, Italic], 
   Style["Max[Abs[Error]]", 16, Italic]}]
```

It's not giving me the desired result. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are on the right track. Let us define your functions and a function to calculate the maximum error:

```
f[x_] := (1/2 x^2 + 3 x) Exp[\[Minus]2*I*π (35/100 x^2 + 2 x)];
ff[x_, α_] := Exp[50 I x - 2 I x^2 Cot[α] - 625 I Sin[2 α]];

abs[α_] := Block[{x},
  First@Maximize[{Abs[(f[x] - ff[x, α])], -Pi <= x <= Pi}, x]
]
```

Then we create a list like you did and plot it.

```
lst = Table[{α, abs[α]}, {α, 0.1, Pi/2, 0.01}];

ListPlot[lst, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["α", 16, Italic], 
   Style["Max[Abs[Error]]", 16, Italic]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. My command is running as well. My result should be a continuous curve rather a random plot as seen in plot. I want to observe some trend in error, decreasing or increasing.